# UIAlertAction completion block not called - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I have an iOS app with a UIAlertController in the form of a action sheet being presented in my app when the user taps on a button.

It all works great, apart from one thing, the completion blocks don't get called for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
// Setup the alert information/type.
UIAlertController *action_view = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Test title" message:@"test message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

// Create and add the cancel button.
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Dismiss" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

    [action_view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"asdhfgjk");
    }];
}];

// Add the action button to the alert.
[action_view addAction:cancel];

// Present the alert to the user.
[self presentViewController:action_view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you run that code you will see the line which dismisses the controller wont run and neither will the `NSLog` statement inside it. However, if you delete the `NSLog` and set the completion block to nil, then it does run.... why???

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Don't attempt to dismiss the alert controller. It will be dismissed for you by the time your alert action's handler is called.

Change the "cancel" action to:

```
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Dismiss" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    NSLog(@"asdhfgjk");
}];
```

Comment: Why the down vote? If there is something wrong with the answer, at least explain what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know who voted you down, but I'm voting your answer up and ticking it as it solved my problem perfectly, thanks. Come to think of it, I don't know why I was under the impression that I need to tell it to dismiss the alert controller anyway.

Comment: Upvoted because it helped me and because I've also been downvoted before without giving a reason.  SO should require a reason to be given on a downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The "cancel" action should not dismiss the view controller as mentioned by rmaddy. However, even if the "cancel" action is set to:

```
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Dismiss" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
NSLog(@"asdhfgjk");}];
```

you may see the same issue with the completion block not being called. For example, implementing this (somewhat contrived) method:

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
   [[self presentedViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:nil];
}
```

could also have this effect because the UIAlertController gets dismissed before the completion block is called.