# iOS - UIAlertController actions not triggering handler

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiviewcontroller, dialog

I'm extremely new to iOS. I'm trying to show a dialog to the user to get some input, but the actions are never triggered. I've been searching on the net for hours and no answer seem to work for me.

Here's the function I'm trying to use to show the dialog:

```
private func showAmountDialog(type: String, onComplete: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter an amount", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: LzStrings.Common_Cancel, style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { textField in
        textField.placeholder = "0.00 \(type)"
        textField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: LzStrings.Common_OK, style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
        if let input = alert.textFields?.first?.text, let amount = Double(input) {
            print("Your amount: \(amount)")
        }
    })

    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

`self` here is my `ViewController` which has a parent of `UIViewController` type and several other protocols.

What I might be doing wrong?

**EDIT**: The way I knew it isn't executing is using break-points and not by relying on `print("...")`

Also, since I added the `TextField` right before adding the action, the nullability check is useless and the `textFields.first` is never `nil`, so in both cases, a break-point should be triggered or the `print("...")` should be executed, which neither of them is happening.

**EDIT 2**: Since the `if statement` can do a little distraction, I edited my code this way and tested again:

```
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: LzStrings.Common_OK, style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
        if let input = alert.textFields?.first {
            if let amount = Double(input.text ?? "") {
                print("Your amount: \(amount)")
            } else {
                print("Can't cast this string to double")
            }
        } else {
            print("Text field is null")
        }
    })
```

Still, no feedback from the `dialog`.
**PS**: Even the Cancel `button` doesn't work.

**EDIT 3**: My dismiss `function` is overridden in the `super` class, but it passes completion `closure` normally:

```
 override open func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    if let navigationController = self.navigationController as? NavigationController {
        navigationController.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
    } else {
        super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working because `print("Your amount: \(amount)")` isn't printed right? Well, is it because `alert.textFields?.first?.text` is nil, or because `Double(input)` is nil?

Comment: As @Larme said, why do you think it's working?

Comment: @Larme, I didn't rely on the output of print(), I put a breakpoint right on the nullability checking line

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: `let amount = Double(input)` is that nil? Is that the cause of the fail? Could you replace your `if let ... {}` with `if let ... {} else { print("oops") }`?

Comment: @Larme, The if statement is not even executed. Please read my Edit, I'm not relying on printing, but on break points.

Comment: @Larme, I edited my question, please check it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696643/uialertaction-handler-is-not-called ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853387/uialertaction-completion-block-not-called-ios? Did you override dismiss method?

Comment: @Larme, for the first link, please check EDIT 3. For the second one I'm using Swift, not Objective-C

Comment: "For the second one": It's the same reason, jsut in Objective-C. It doesn't matter it's the same framework behind, same logic. And what if you comment that line just to check if that fix it, and then we'll focus on that overridden method?

Comment: I'm extremely new to iOS, I can barely write swift code, I cannot understand Objective-C that's why I didn't include it in my tags)

Answer (score 0):

After having a conversation with one of my colleagues, we found out that to show standard `UIAlertController` we must use this:

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Instead of this

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It fixed my issue. I hope someone will find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an extention for ViewController:

```
extension UIViewController {
    //Show a basic alert
    func showAlert(alertText : String, alertMessage : String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: alertText, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        //Add more actions as you see fit
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```